# Create Function Using Predicate

Tags: java, function, java-8, conditional-statements, predicate

I am new to Java 8 , I am trying with Predicate and Function. I have my pojo class Product, which has Long Id , String category. I create predicate fruits & Drinks which check the Id between 1000 to 2000 and 3000 to 4000 respectively.

I also created a Function which will set the category as "Fruits" / "Drinks" to the product object. Now to check the id range of the product I use predicate in Conditional Statement which shows error to me as "Multiple Markers", when same code is placed in if/else block works absolutely as expected

//Predicate

```
          Predicate <Product> checkFruitsLimitProduct = (product) -> product.getId().intValue() >= 1000 && product.getId().intValue() < 2000;

    Predicate <Product> checkDrinksLimitProduct = (product) -> product.getId().intValue() >= 3000 && product.getId().intValue() < 4000;
```

//Function with Conditional Statement

```
      Function <Product, Product> setCategory = (product) -> {

        checkFruitsLimitProduct.test(product) ? product.setCategory("Fruits") : checkDrinksLimitProduct.test(product))?
                product.setCategory("YS") : product.setCategory("YS");
    return product;

    };
```

//Function with If/else block which works fine

```
        Function <Product, Product> setCategory = (product) -> {
                 if(checkFruitsLimitProduct.test(product)) {
            product.setCategory("Fruits") ;
        }else if(checkDrinksLimitProduct.test(product)) {
            product.setCategory("Drinks");
        }else {
            product.setCategory("YS");
        }
     return product;
      };
```

//Print function Values

```
          Product p1 = new Product(1000L);
          Product p2 = new Product(3000L);
          System.out.println(setCategory.apply(p1));
      System.out.println(setCategory.apply(p2));
```

With Conditional Statement error as : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems

Comment: You're trying to run code that doesn't compile. Don't do that. **Read** the compilation error messages and fix them. Once all are fixed, then an only then you should start running your code.

Comment: @JBNizet, Acutally i am not sure where is the fix. The same code works fine in If/Else and not in conditional Statement.

Comment: That's why you need to read the error message from the compiler. It tells what is wrong, and where.

Comment: Your indentation is a mess. Could you please fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator shouldn't really be used for side-effects. However, if you want to accomplish the nested ternary to set the category you should return `Product` from `setCategory`

```
public Product setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
    return this;
}
```

Then your `Function` could be written as

```
Function<Product, Product> setCategory = (product) -> checkFruitsLimitProduct.test(product) ? product.setCategory("Fruits") :
        checkDrinksLimitProduct.test(product) ? product.setCategory("Drinks") : product.setCategory("YS");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't do this:

```
product.getId().intValue()
```

Imagine what happen if there is a long bigger than max integer.No need to cast to int.

Secondly, you don't need a Function. A function have an input and an output.
But what you really want there is to update an input. For this, it exists Consumer.
And to use ternary, you put the condition inside `product.setCategory(condition goes here);` like this:

```
Consumer<Product> setCategory = (product) ->  product.setCategory( checkFruitsLimitProduct.test(product) ? "Fruits" :checkDrinksLimitProduct.test(product) ? "Drinks":"YS")
```

Instead of apply, you have accept method:

```
Product p1 = new Product(1000L);
setCategory.accept(p1);
System.out.println(p1.getCategory());
```